# Discord Py send message to specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on my discord bot.
I'm making an order to send a message to a specific room except I can't make it... Here's my code:

```
@client.command(name='say', help='Dire un message à votre place')
@commands.has_permissions(send_messages=True, manage_messages=True)
async def say(ctx, message, channelid):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message", color=discord.Color.dark_red())
    embed.add_field(name="Nouveau message de {}".format(ctx.message.author), value="{}".format(message))
    embed.set_footer(text="{}".format(ctx.message.author))
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

and here's the error I'm getting in the terminal.

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send"
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

PS : My bot is in french

Comment: Looks like `client.get_channel(channelid)` can't find required channel, so it returns `None` value. Are you sure `channelid` is correct?

Comment: the message I'm sending on discord is ```c?say message 720347475361267843```

Comment: UP Please !! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a message as string more then one word, by doing:

```
@client.command(name='say', help='Dire un message à votre place')
@commands.has_permissions(send_messages=True, manage_messages=True)
async def say(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, message):
    #Embed making
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message", color=discord.Color.dark_red())
    embed.add_field(name="Nouveau message de {}".format(ctx.message.author), value="{}".format(message))
    embed.set_footer(text="{}".format(ctx.message.author))

    await channel.send(embed=e)
```

The colon and discord.Channel signifies you need to enter an `#channel` format on discord screen
Also to have a multi letter message, do this:

```
async def say(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, *msg):
    message = " ".join(msg)
    #Embed making
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message", color=discord.Color.dark_red())
    embed.add_field(name="Nouveau message de {}".format(ctx.message.author), value="{}".format(message))
    embed.set_footer(text="{}".format(ctx.message.author))

    await channel.send(embed=e)
```

the star sign makes it a tuple, So if you do

```
c?say #text-channel-send Hello and Bye
```

So Hello, and, bye are parts of a tuple, like this: `('Hello','and','bye')` so when you do

```
" ".join(msg)
```

it joins the elements of tuple to give you a string, separeted by spaces. It works for lists too.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have this mistake : ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 74, in <module>
    async def say(ctx, channel:discord.Channel, message):
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is part of a code that can get you started! I have recently made this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="│arrivals")
    await channel.send(f"Welcome to Sleep's Gaming Cult {member.mention}! You are the ### member")
```

You can than change `name` to `id` and put your channel id instead of "│arrivals"! I have not test this out but this my best guess that it will work! Of course this is an example for when someone joins but you can use this for any command!

Comment: I have this mistake
```Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'member' is not defined```